# How to override Django AuthenticationForm inactive message

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to display a custom error message when an account exists but is inactive. To do this I am overrriding the [AuthenticationForm's](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) `error_messages`.

**forms.py**:

```
class AuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': (
            "This custom message works"
        ),
        'inactive': (
            "This custom message does not."
        ),
    }
```

**urls.py**:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='employees/login.html',
        authentication_form=AuthForm),
         name='login'),
```

As you can see the inactive message does not work. Thoughts on why?

Edit: when inactive accounts try to login the `invalid_login` message shows and not the `inactive`, message.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug which exists](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28645#no2) in Django. There is also [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459258/how-to-inform-a-user-that-he-is-not-active-in-django-login-view/46459998#46459998) which discusses this issue.